# GoogleAppEngine Python installation can't find .dmg file

Tags: installation, google-app-engine-python

I downloaded the Google App Engine SDK for Python from [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Python), extracted the zip file, but there's no dmg file that allows me to install it. Here's what the ReadMe says:

```
INSTALLING ON Mac OSX
=====================
1) Download and install Python 2.7 from http://www.python.org/download/
2) Download the SDK installer from
https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads
3) Install the SDK by double-clicking on the GoogleAppEngine.dmg file and
running the installer.
```

I checked every folder but there is no such file! Maybe the ReadMe is obsolete. Please help..
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I didn't click the button--thought it was just a check image.

Comment: So is the program Google AppEngine Launcher just gone???  I used that in my App Engine class. ;)  Guess I'll be teaching students to use the command line.